# Pyspark Window function: Counting number of categorical variables and calculating percentages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe of the below format. There are different IDs, and product names and types associated for each product.

```
ID  Prod Name   Type    Total Qty
1   ABC             A   200
1   DEF             B   350
1   GEH             B   120
1   JIK             C   100
1   LMO             A   40
2   ABC             A   10
2   DEF             A   20
2   GEH             C   30
2   JIK             C   40
2   LMO             A   50
```

So I am trying to get the percentage of total A's, B's and C's for that product name and ID in a separate column. As a first step, I was trying to use window function, but it gave me the count of "A" across the whole column.

```
df.withColumn("count_cat", F.count("Type").over(Window.partitionBy("Type")))
```

But I need something like this

```
ID  total Products  Total Qty   % of A  % of B  % of C
1   5                 810        0.29    0.58    0.12
```

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean by  "the percentage of total A's, B's and C's for that product name and ID", in the example output you show, B is 0.58% which is neither the percentage of `Type` column characters with respect to `ID` and neither the percentage of A B C character in `Prod Name` with respect to `ID`.  
Could you show how you got thos percentages? which don't really add to 100% furthermore

Comment: @nonoDa So the percentages are from the "total qty". so for A - it is 240/810 = 0.29

Answer (score 4):

### Approach 1: Group By Aggregation

Based on your expected output, aggregates based on a `GROUP BY Id` would be sufficient.

You may achieve this using the following assuming your initial dataset is stored in a dataframe `input_df`

#### Using spark sql

1. ensure your dataframe is accessible by creating a temporary view

```py
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df")
```

2. Running the sql below on your spark session

```py
output_df = sparkSession.sql("""
SELECT
     ID,
     COUNT(Prod_Name) as `total products`,
     SUM(Total_Qty) as `Total Qty`,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN Type='A' THEN Total_Qty END
     ) / SUM(Total_Qty) as `% of A`,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN Type='B' THEN Total_Qty END
     ) / SUM(Total_Qty) as `% of B`,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN Type='C' THEN Total_Qty END
     ) / SUM(Total_Qty) as `% of C`
FROM
    input_df
GROUP BY
    ID
""").na.fill(0)
```

#### Using the pyspark API

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    input_df.groupBy("ID")
            .agg(
                F.count("Prod_Name").alias("total products"),
                F.sum("Total_Qty").alias("Total Qty"),
                (F.sum(
                    F.when(
                        F.col("Type")=="A",F.col("Total_Qty")
                    ).otherwise(0)
                ) / F.sum("Total_Qty")).alias("% of A"),
                (F.sum(
                    F.when(
                        F.col("Type")=="B",F.col("Total_Qty")
                    ).otherwise(0)
                )/ F.sum("Total_Qty")).alias("% of B"),
                (F.sum(
                    F.when(
                        F.col("Type")=="C",F.col("Total_Qty")
                    ).otherwise(0)
                )/ F.sum("Total_Qty")).alias("% of C")
            )
)
```

### Approach 2: Using Windows

If it is that you would like to add these as 5 addition columns to your dataset you may use similar aggregations with the following window `OVER (PARTITION BY ID)` or `Window.partitionBy("ID")` as shown below

#### Using spark sql

1. ensure your dataframe is accessible by creating a temporary view

```py
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df")
```

2. Running the sql below on your spark session

```py
output_df = sparkSession.sql("""
SELECT
     *,
     COUNT(Prod_Name) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as `total products`,
     SUM(Total_Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as `Total Qty`,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN Type='A' THEN Total_Qty END
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) / SUM(Total_Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as `% of A`,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN Type='B' THEN Total_Qty END
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)/ SUM(Total_Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as `% of B`,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN Type='C' THEN Total_Qty END
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) / SUM(Total_Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as `% of C`
FROM
    input_df
GROUP BY
    ID
""").na.fill(0)
```

#### Using the pyspark API

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

agg_window = Window.partitionBy("Id")

output_df = (
    input_df.withColumn(
                "total products",
                F.count("Prod_Name").over(agg_window)
            )
            .withColumn(
                "Total Qty",
                F.sum("Total_Qty").over(agg_window)
            )
            .withColumn(
                "% of A",
                F.sum(
                    F.when(
                        F.col("Type")=="A",F.col("Total_Qty")
                    ).otherwise(0)
                ).over(agg_window) / F.sum("Total_Qty").over(agg_window)
            )
            .withColumn(
                "% of B",
                F.sum(
                    F.when(
                        F.col("Type")=="B",F.col("Total_Qty")
                    ).otherwise(0)
                ).over(agg_window) / F.sum("Total_Qty").over(agg_window)
            )
            .withColumn(
                "% of C",
                F.sum(
                    F.when(
                        F.col("Type")=="C",F.col("Total_Qty")
                    ).otherwise(0)
                ).over(agg_window) / F.sum("Total_Qty").over(agg_window)
            )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

One approach (without repeating A B C etc), is using pivot. The idea is grouping first then pivoting the type:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    .groupBy('ID', 'Type')
    .agg(F.sum('Total Qty').alias('qty'))
    .withColumn('pct', F.col('qty') / F.sum('qty').over(W.partitionBy('ID')))
 
    .groupBy('ID')
    .pivot('Type')
    .agg(F.first('pct'))
    .show()
)

# Output
# +---+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
# | ID|                 A|                 B|                  C|
# +---+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
# |  1|0.2962962962962963|0.5802469135802469|0.12345679012345678|
# |  2|0.5333333333333333|              null| 0.4666666666666667|
# +---+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```